# the system cannot find the file specified while importing json data in couchbase bucket.

Tags: json, couchbase

**I apologize if my question does not deserve a standard to ask here.**

I have two files(products-data.json, orders-data.json) inside the following directory:

```
G:\kb\Couchbase\CB121
```

and I imported the products-data.json successfully using the following command:

```
G:\kb\Couchbase\CB121>cbimport.exe json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u sattar -p 156271 -b sampleDB -f lines -d file://products-data.json -t 4 -g %type%::%variety%::#MONO_INCR#
```

But when I try to import orders-data.json in the same way as follows:

```
 G:\kb\Couchbase\CB121>cbimport.exe json -c couchbase://127.0.0.1 -u sattar -p 156271 -b sampleDB -f lines -d file://orders-data.json​ -t 4 -g ​%type%::%order_id%
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2018-01-21T12:01:31.211+06:00 [31mERRO: open orders-data.json​: The system cannot find the file specified.[0m[2m -- jsondata.(*Parallelizer).Execute() at source.go:198[0m
2018-01-21T12:01:31.212+06:00 [31mERRO: open orders-data.json​: The system cannot find the file specified.[0m[2m -- plan.(*data).execute() at data.go:89[0m
Json import failed: open orders-data.json​: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It kills my day. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the obvious questions are: does the file actually exist? Is there a difference in file permission?

Comment: YES, I checked again. file actually exist and the permission is same as products-data.json

Comment: Try to open products-data.json with another app, for example a python/node simple script and verify the outcome.

Comment: You want to post the files (here or on forums.couchbase.com) to see if myself (or others) can reproduce.

Comment: Thanks. It is resolved without any change. I restart my pc and type the command. It works.